# How to display several image_tag inside an iteration in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration, helper

I'm trying to create a helper to display rating stars based on a model attribute.

I have the following:

```
  def show_profile_stars(profile)
    content_tag :span, :class => 'stars' do
      profile.stars.times do
        image_tag("stars.gif", :size => "30x30", :class => "gold")
      end
    end
  end
```

'stars' is an integer field.

But it's not rendering the image tags, instead it just displays the 'stars' number literally.

If I put just image_tag without the iteration block it does show the image, the problem is with the iteration.

I guess I'm missing something about methods that receive blocks (I'm still new at RoR).

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, wouldn't this be done in CSS using a class on the span (e.g. one-star, two-star, etc)?

Anyway, to actually do what you want to do try:

```
stars = []
profile.stars.times { stars << image_tag("stars.gif", :size => "30x30", :class => "gold") }
content_tag :span, stars.join("\n").html_safe, :class => "stars"
```

Comment: I just have an image of 1 star. People can have from 0 stars to many... so I need to display the correct ammount of stars depending on the attribute. I'll try your method, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `concat` helper:

```
def show_profile_stars(profile)
  content_tag :span, :class => 'stars' do
    profile.stars.times do
      concat(image_tag("stars.gif", :size => "30x30", :class => "gold"))
    end

    nil
  end
end
```

You also need to return `nil` at the end of the `content_tag` so that it doesn't output `stars`.